# Best way to do conditional assignment in python

Tags: python

I tend to use this a lot, but it's ugly:

```
a = (lambda x: x if x else y)(get_something())
```

So I wrote this function:

```
def either(val, alt):
    if val:
        return val
    else:
        return alt
```

So you can do:

```
a = either(get_something(), y)
```

Is there a built-in function for this (similar to ISNULL in T-SQL)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `or` operator does what you want:

```
get_something() or y
```

In fact, it's chainable, like `COALESCE` (and unlike `ISNULL`). The following expression evaluates to the left-most argument that converts to True.

```
A or B or C
```

Comment: Thanks. Ha, I was actually trying that but dismissed it when trying 'a = 0 or None' and the console printed nothing. But trying 'a is None' after that gives 'True', plus I want 'None or 0' functionality anyway (getting late) :) By the way, thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Just for the record, if you're to chain `and` operator, it will evaluate to right-most argument that converts to True if all arguments or the left-most argument that converts to False if any converts to False.

Comment: "a = 0 or None" Well of course the console won't print anything, you're assigning the result of `0 or None` to `a`, and variables with `None` assigned to them don't automatically display `None` when shown in the console. You have to specifically use `repr`, `str`, or `print`. Or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

You may use:

```
a = get_something() or y
```

If `get_something` is `True` in boolean context, its value will be assigned to `a`. Otherwise - `y` will be assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 7):

Easy!

For more conditional code:

```
a = b if b else val
```

For your code:

```
a = get_something() if get_something() else val
```

With that you can do complex conditions like this:

```
a = get_something() if get_something()/2!=0 else val
```

Comment: Except this calls `get_something` twice.

Comment: can put get_somthing into a variable . Just only with OR you cant put conditions to work.

Comment: Because the builtin `or` operator is simpler, and doesn't compute the expression twice.  The OP is aware of the ternary conditional, buy looked for something simpler.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple `or`, like so:

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = 1
>>> c = (a or b) # parentheses are optional
>>> c
1
```

Answer (score 3):

I have provided an answer to this question to another user. Check it out here:

[Answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402311/python-conditional-assignment-operator/12985732#12985732)

To respond quickly here, do:

```
x = true_value if condition else false_value
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using the `(a,b)[condition based on the value of a]` form, saving the result of the `get_something()` call into `a`, in the rare cases that are best presented here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-September/785515.html

```
...
a=0     b=None     a or b => None      (a,b)[a is None] => 0
a=()    b=None     a or b => None      (a,b)[a is None] => ()
...
```

Comment: I see. This would be if you wanted to check `a` for a more specific condition. But you need two lines so I would go with `a = x if condition else y` which is more readable. Interesting syntax though. Never seen anything like it :)

Comment: @crizCraig: added a short example