# Python equivalent of Perl/Ruby ||=

Tags: python, ruby, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python conditional assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402311/python-conditional-assignment-operator)

Apologies for such a simple question, but googling `||=` isn't very helpful ;)

Is there an equivalent in Python to the `||=` statement that's present in Ruby and Perl?

For example:

```
foo = "hey"
foo ||= "what"    # assign foo if it's undefined
# foo is still "hey"

bar ||= "yeah"
# bar is "yeah"
```

Also what's the general term for something like this? Conditional assignment was my first guess but the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:) isn't quite what I had in mind.

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate it seems. Thanks Adam!

Comment: `$foo ||= "what"` will reassign `$foo` if it is already *false*. Of course `undef` is false, but then so is zero and the null string. To reassign only an undefined value use slashes instead, like `$foo //= "what"`

Comment: Note that `//` (and its extension, `//=`) was added in perl 5.10.  If you're still stuck on 5.8.x, you won't be able to use `//=` (and you should seriously consider upgrading if at all possible).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A tad bit more verbose, but the easiest is

```
foo = "hey"
foo = foo or "what"
#foo is still "hey"

bar = None
bar = bar or "yeah"
#bar is "yeah"
```

You can also use the ternary operator

```
bar = None
bar = bar if bar else "yeah"
```

However, if I understand you, `||=` assigns variables that weren't previously defined, without complaint? I had no idea.

To do that in the local scope, this ugly duckling could work

```
bar = locals()['bar'] if 'bar' in locals() else 'yeah'
```

EDIT:

Just saw the duplicate, and it has plenty of solutions as well :) For those too lazy to look, they also include a nicer variant on my last one

```
foo = foo if 'foo' in locals() else 'hey'
```

but this won't work for undefined variables, only falsy values will be replaced and undefined will raise a `NameError`. This next one will, OTOH, ONLY work for undefined and always keep the same preexisting falsy value, which as @Borodin says is like `//=` in Perl

```
foo = locals().get('foo','hey')
```

and, of course, someone used an exception :(

```
try:
   v
except NameError:
   v = 'bla bla'
```

Comment: no, `||=` will reassign a variable if it is `false`. See my comment on the question. Why would you expect a complaint?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at first I didn't notice the nuanced difference. the `bar = None` is required for it to work, otherwise it throws a `NameError`. For identical behaviour you need your `locals()['bar']` snippet. Thanks again :)

Comment: @borodin I'm not a Rubyist, I've only used it for silly stuff like Chef. I just meant that I didn't know that `undef` in Ruby was falsey, since that's not the case in Python (undefined references throw exceptions). Regardless, thanks for your comments, I learned something :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll hardly ever have undefined variables in Python, and when you do it usually means you have made a mistake. However, conveniently, most of the sorts of values that are commonly used as defaults (empty containers, zero-length strings, zero, and `None`) are "falsy" in Python, so you will sometimes see stuff like this that takes advantage of how Boolean operators work in Python:

```
name = name or "Guido"   # if name is empty, set it to "Guido"
numb = numb or 42        # if numb is zero, set it to 42
```

The reason this works is that Python stops evaluating `or` if the first argument is "truthy," which is called short-circuiting, and in either case returns the actual argument, rather than merely `True` or `False`, as its result.  So if `name` is "Jim" then `"Jim" or "Guido"` evaluates to `"Jim"` because `"Jim"` is a non-zero-length string and therefore "truthy."

Of course, this doesn't work so well when you don't know the type of the value you're dealing with and/or a "falsy" value is a valid value. However, it works pretty well with things like configuration files and `raw_input()` where a missing value will return an empty string:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ") or "Guido"
```

Another common idiom is used when dealing with items in a dictionary. The dictionary class's `get()` method lets you specify a default value to be used if the variable isn't in the dictionary.

```
name = values.get("name", "Guido")
```

This can be used when your function has been passed keyword arguments using the `**kwargs` convention. You *could* also use it with variables, as the `globals()` and `locals()` functions return, respectively, all global or local variables currently in scope as a dictionary:

```
name = locals().get("name", "Guido")
```

However, as I said, you will rarely ever have actually undefined variables in Python. In cases like Web frameworks, you'll be passed query string arguments as a dictionary, for example, and can use the dictionary's `.get()` method on it.

In the rare case where a name actually does not exist (for example, your configuration file is in Python syntax and you're importing it as a Python module rather than parsing it, and you want users to be able to omit some values... or something equally wacky) then you can use `getattr()`, which (like dictionary's `.get()`) accepts a default value:

```
import config
name = getattr(config, "name", "Guido")    # rather than just name.config
```

Or just let it throw a `NameError` and catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the name.  The best I could come up with is:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> a = 'a' in locals() and a or 'what'
>>> a
'foo'
>>> b = 'b' in locals() and b or 'yeah'
>>> b
'yeah'
```