# Set keyword argument's default value as length of string

Tags: python, python-class

I've taken up a challenge to recreate some popular Python functions, one of them being `string.count()`. Other than the substring argument and the start index (optional), it also takes the end index (optional as well). This is my code:

```
def count(self,substring,start=0):
    self.substring = substring
    self.start = start

    self.queue = 0
    self.counter = 0

    for a in self.string[start:]:
        if a == self.substring[0]:
            self.queue += 1
        if a == self.substring[len(self.substring) - 1] and self.queue != 0:
            self.queue -= 1
            self.counter += 1

    return self.counter
```

Some variables I have defined outside of this function: `self.string`, which is the original string itself. You can see that I have not included the `end` argument, and that is why I'm here today. I would like to set the argument as: `end=len(self.string) - 1`, but it just throws and error and says: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. Is there a solution to this? So far I can say that my code is not the problem, since it works perfectly without the argument, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Are you using Classes? Cuz if you do please provide whole code. If not then self has no meaning here.

Comment: Try create a variable `end` inside the function and give it the len() value, maybe you can't access variables inside the argument space.

Comment: Yes I'm using classes, but I don't think I need to provide whole code, because only self.string is related to this function

Comment: Throughout this code, you are storing local values as instance attributes. The instance of the class will be keeping a copy of the last substring that was counted, the last start location, the value of counter, and the value of queue. These values should be stored in locals (i.e. drop the "self." from the start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's categorize parameters into 3 types:

- required (positional) parameter (like `substring`)
- optional parameter (like `start`, `end`), often with `None` as type-less placeholder
- parameter with [default argument values](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) (like `start`, `end`)

See also:

- ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)
- Effbot/Fredrik Lundh (July 17, 2008): [Default Parameter Values in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm), via Wayback archive, **using `None` as default value**

### Use slicing and default for `end` parameter

See also the [runnable demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/g8Iidg):

```py
class StringUtil:

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.string = s
    
    
    def count(self, substring, start=0, end=-1):  # end index/slice: -1 for the last, instead len(self.substring) - 1
        self.substring = substring
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.queue = 0
        self.counter = 0

        for a in self.string[start:]:
            if a == self.substring[0]:
                self.queue += 1
            if a == self.substring[end] and self.queue != 0:  # -1 for the last, instead len(self.substring) - 1
                self.queue -= 1
                self.counter += 1
        
        return self.counter


sub = "o*o"
s =  "Hell" + sub + " W" + sub + "rld"
cnt = StringUtil(s).count(sub)
print(f" counted '{sub}' in '{s}' times: {cnt}")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think one simple solution is the following

```
def count(self,substring,start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(self.string) - 1
    self.substring = substring
    self.start = start
    self.end = end # i suppose this needs to be set

    self.queue = 0
    self.counter = 0

    for a in self.string[start:]:
        if a == self.substring[0]:
            self.queue += 1
        if a == self.substring[len(self.substring) - 1] and self.queue != 0:
            self.queue -= 1
            self.counter += 1
    
    return self.counter
```

Comment: Practical solution with a placeholder `None`. ️ The evaluation can be simplified as ️ [_conditional assignment_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402311/python-conditional-assignment-operator) to:  `self.end = len(substring) -1 if not end else end`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that `end` is a null value, then `end = None` in  parentheses of `def count()`:

```py
def count(substring, start = 0, end = None):
    # implementation omitted
```

Later, thanks to the null value of `end`, you can create a condition inside the function, that is, if end is a null value, then end is `-1`.

You can write `if end is None: end = len (self.string) - 1`